# How to move JavaScript function with dynamic name from MVC razor view to JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Razor View, I have some JavaScript functions with dynamic names, such as:

```
function @(GridName)_FunctionName() {
    return true;
}
```

My goal is to move such functions to my .js file. Can you please advise if there is an easy (clean) way to do that?

Comment: TBH sounds like a bad idea - might be better served as `function FunctionName(gridName)` then call it with `FunctionName('@GridName')` or `FunctionName(this)` - depends on what each function does.

Comment: *My goal is to move such functions to my .js file* note that unless you make some dodgy changes to how your server serves .js files (and don't do that), Razor code doesn't run in `.js` files as they're not "server-side" files.